# Appropriate approach to supplier integration

Tags: c#, xml, design-patterns, linq-to-xml, integration

In the project I am working now we pull some data from over 40 different suppliers via their web services and then aggregate them together before showing to our customers.
Each supplier offers different type of service (some requests we send are SOAP calls, some are simple query string via POST or GET, and other...).
At the moment the system is a little bit messy, we have a base class that has an abstract method called *GetSupplierData(Request request)* that each individual supplier class overrides. The problem is that each supplier class does completly different stuff inside of that method, setting timeouts on different parts of request etc. My task is to implement a common business logic/timing/logging accross all suppliers and so I think this method should be changed.
The overall process can be broken up to 4 different stages according to business logic:

- Generate a supplier-specific request
- Send that request and wait for the response
- Map the response to a common format (call that class *CommonResponse* )
- Post-process the *CommonResponse* (here the logic is common to all suppliers and so is implemented in the base class)

According to this logic I have decided to implement a Template Method Design Pattern, I created a business logic method in the base class and 3 abstract methods representing first 3 steps from the business logic above:

```
public class SupplierBase
{
    protected abstract XDocument generateRequest(Request request);
    protected abstract XDocument sendRequest(XDocument request);
    protected abstract CommonResponse mapResponse(XDocument response);

    public CommonResponse process(Request request)
    {
        return mapResponse(sendRequest(generateRequest(request)));
    }
}
```

What I don't like though is that we operate on XDocument (so we create supplier requests using Linq To XML) instead of some kind of proxy objects. On the other hand I am not sure how to go about implementing template pattern if we were to pass so many completely different proxy objects in and out of the functions. I know that at some point every request can be (or even in some cases *have to be*) represented by XML, and I know that return from every supplier is an XML, and thus I decided to go with XDocument instead of mapped supplier-specific objects representing that xml (and serializing/deserializing).
Nevertheless I have a strange feeling this could be done better.
Has any of you done something similar in the past? How did you go about it? I will be greatful for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couldn't you do it with generics and use the proxy objects?  something like

```
public abstract class SupplierBase<TRequest, TResponse>
    {
        protected abstract TRequest generateRequest();
        protected abstract TResponse sendRequest (TRequest request);
        protected abstract CommonResponse mapResponse (TResponse request);

        public CommonResponse process(TRequest request)
        {
            return mapResponse(sendRequest(generateRequest()));
        }
    }

    // an implementing class...
    public class SupplierA:SupplierBase<RequestA, ResponseA>
    {
        protected override RequestA generateRequest()
        {
            return new RequestA();
        }

        protected override ResponseA sendRequest(RequestA request)
        {
            // call with the request and return the specific response
        }

        protected override CommonResponse mapResponse(ResponseA request)
        {
            // map the specific response to the common response
        }
    }
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I will check this out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar project. It sounds very similar to what you are working on.

Since I need a history of the supplier responses, I have the individual supplier classes write the response into the database (after parsing the relevant parts of the response), and later access it from the main thread.